# Delete nodes in TreeView which is filled from the database ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, treeview

I have a TreeView which filled from the database. The table in DB have such fields: Id, ParentId, Name.

ParentId - Saves the id element in which it is laid. (0 if it is an independent element).

When a user enters the name of the node to be deleted, I need to remove all subChild in this node.

How to remove all node elements and not just selected?

Maybe recursion? Record id in an array of elements that need to be further removed, and then in a loop to delete all?

My attempt remove elements:

```
    public void findChild(int selectedId)
    {
        DataSet PrSet = PDataset("SELECT Id, ParentID FROM companies"); //get data from database
        foreach (DataRow dr in PrSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (int.Parse(dr["ParentID"].ToString()) == SelectedId)
            {
                index.Add(int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString())); //add id to list
                findChild(int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here in the picture, for example, I need to remove the Avaya site. That is, you need to remove elements [2, 3, 4, 5, Comp3, Avaya]. Also i need remove this elements from database.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DECI.png)

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. It's not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are referring to the application then just reset the tree viewer to get the data from the database.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i was resolved this problem by use recursion